# HTML form not working. Isset POST doesn't work PHP.

Tags: php, html

I want add records into the base but not all. I have checkboxes and if some is checked then I add into the base if i click input button Save("Zapisz zmiany").
But input button save doesn't work. No reaction. POST array is empty. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Input button:

```
<form action"" method="post" >
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Zamknij/Close" />
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name"zapros" id="zapros" value="Zapisz zmiany" />
</form>
```

and:

```
     <?php   
 if (isset($_POST['zapros']))    {              
       $sqlc=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');                        
       if($sqlc)  {
        $sql_q="USE aplikacja";
        mysqli_query($sqlc,$sql_q);
        $data_zaproszenia = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql_q=mysqli_query($sqlc, "SELECT * FROM goscie WHERE Email_goscia= '$mail'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_q) != 0)
        {
          for ($i=1; $i < $lp ; $i++) 
          { 
            if (isset($_POST['zaznacz'.$i.''])) 
            {
              $data_waznosci = $_POST['data_waznosci'.$i.''];
              $sql_zaproszenie=mysqli_query($sqlc, "INSERT INTO zaproszenia (Email_goscia, ID_kwestionariusza, ID_wyniku, Data_zaproszenia, Data_waznosci, Wynik, Ocena, Status) 
              VALUES ('$mail', $id, NULL, '$data_zaproszenia', '$data_waznosci', NULL, NULL, 'Status')");  //dodawanie kolejnych odpowiedzi do bazy
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Zaproszenie wysłano!');</script>";
              header('Refresh: 0;url=zaproszenia.php?id='.$id.'');
            }
            else
            {
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Zaproszenie NIE wysłano!');</script>";
              $i++;
            } 
          }
        }
        mysqli_close($sqlc);        
        }
          else
          {
            echo mysqli_connect_errno();
          } 
        }?>
```

Comment: change the type to `type="submit"`

Comment: `But input button save doesn't work` because it does not submit the form. And not supposed to. Read the manuals about html forms.

Comment: Even if an `type="button"` would submit the form the `zapros` would be empty as you are missing a `=` here `name"zapros"`

Comment: You have right. Works. One question yet. Is a checkbox you can use isset? If not, how to check if the checkbox is selected in php ?

Comment: If it's a button you want to use, then use `<button type="submit" name"zapros">Zapisz zmiany</button>`. Otherwise, it needs to be an `type="submit"`.

Comment: Whenever a `checkbox` is check then the `value` will be send with `name` set for the checkbox, if it is not checked, then it will not be submitted and therefor will not be set.

Comment: Bad title of question.  Should be something to do with the POST array being missing or the HTML form not working.  OP recognizes the $_POST is empty, so of course `isset()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't even examined your PHP, but you have some errors in your HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Zamknij/Close" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="zapros" id="zapros" value="Zapisz zmiany" />
</form>
```

You were missing `=` signs in two places (`action=` and `name=`), and were using a button instead of a submit button.

Comment: Probably the name that caused the issue.  Action can be left out since it defaults to the current page.

Comment: Perhaps the action can be left out if desired, but it was `action""`, which is a syntax error. ;)